# Which OAuth2 Grant to use when developing SPA, Mobile App with Laravel as backend. Will not be using third party login

Tags: laravel, oauth, passport.js

I'm developing a mobile app + SPA using Laravel as a web service. I'm not sure which grant flow will be good for this. I would avoid any third party login like facebook, google, etc. Id'like to handle user login simply with email and password. I want user to login only once on mobile app.

I had gone through some articles. I'm very confused. I found out 2 flows which might work here. 1st is implicit Grant & 2nd one is password grant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If SPA is built inside your Laravel project you can handle user login simply with standard laravel authorization method. 
For external use (mobile app or external SPA) you should authenticate users with API.
Laravel Passport mainly offers two way to handle this.

1. [Personal Access Token](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#personal-access-tokens)
2. [Fresh API Token](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript)

I suggest using the second one cause is the "Standard way" to consuming your web app with a nonsecure source.

Comment: Do i have to create client id for all my users. Yes, SPA is build inside my laravel project. I used Fresh API token. And now i working on developing native app. My problem is this is my first time working on such workflow. I am very confused and lost. I want my native mobile app users to login only once. There are many tables comes with passport installation. Even if i use fresh api token how il be able to keep my mobile user login all the time?

Comment: is there any tutorials available on youtube? or any other website with same scenarios

Comment: You can handle token lifetime by configuring [AuthServiceProvider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#token-lifetimes).

Comment: If you wanna make your life easier just use [Personal Access Token](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#personal-access-tokens). You can handle mobile app login with something like this: `if(Auth::attempt($reuest->only('email','password')){ $token = $user->createToken('testToken')->accessToken;}` and return `$token` to your mobile app.

Comment: Yes. I will try both methods. Thank You..! One more question i have. I have checked my oauth_clients tables. There we can put my clients. my question is, if i have 100 uesrs then i have create 100 clients. client = app. there will only one app on playstore and these 100 will download this app. am just asking.. i didnt get this clients etc etc .. any way.. thanks il try and will reply here.

Comment: `oauth_clients` table contains every token issued by your web app. Every instance of your mobile app will "point" on this table.

Comment: ok! Am trying out one example. Let see. il get back thanks again